# TypeError: environment.setup is not a function in React Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, package

I was trying to implement the example shown in Jest website: [Getting started with Jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html).

While running `npm test` on I was getting the following error:

```
FAIL  src/sum.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: environment.setup is not a function

      at node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:112:23
```

`sum.js`:

```
function sum(a, b){
  return a+b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

`sum.test.js`:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adding sum function', () => {
  expect(sum(234,4)).toBe(238);
})
```

`sum.js` and `sum.test.js` are an exact copy of the example shown in [Getting started with Jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html).

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "jest-demo-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^22.0.4"
  }
}
```

So, how can I get rid of `TypeError: environment.setup is not a function` error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jest is included with react-scripts. The error is due to a conflict that arose when you installed Jest in a project started with react-scripts. The "Getting started with Jest" guide expects a 'clean' project.

Simply remove Jest from your (dev)dependencies and it should work.

If you want to use Jest for testing React components (which you probably do), you need to modify your test script in `package.json` to `react-scripts test --env=jsdom`, as it was.

Comment: straight from the horse's mouth: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5119#issuecomment-357676403

Comment: I have the same issue, but I am not using create react app

Answer (score 12):

<strike>Based on this github issue: [@jest-environment node not working in v22](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5119),</strike>

I updated the `sum.test.js` as:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

const sum = require('./sum');

test('adding sum function', () => {
  expect(sum(234,4)).toBe(238);
})
```

<strike>Now I got rid of the `TypeError: environment.setup is not a function`.</strike>

Output:

```
PASS  src/sum.test.js
  ✓ adding sum function (2ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.438s
Ran all test suites.
```

---

### Updated

Reading several answers, today I recreated the scenario.

**Step 1:**
I created a new project using `create-react-app`.

The command: `create-react-app demo-app`

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "demo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

This file shows that `jest` is not included in the dependencies.

**Step 2:**
I included `sum.js` and `sum.test.js` files in `src` folder as shown in the official [getting started guide](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html).

`sum.js`:

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

`sum.test.js`:

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

**Step 3:**
I ran `yarn test` command without including `jest` in `package.json` file.
So, this test command uses `react-scripts test --env=jsdom` as shown in `package.json`.

Output of the test:

```
PASS  src/sum.test.js
PASS  src/App.test.js

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.594s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

**Step 4:**
I updated the `package.json` file to use `jest` as test script:

```
{
  "name": "demo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Again I ran `yarn test` and the output is:

```
$ jest
 PASS  src/sum.test.js
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /<PATH>/demo-app/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (7:18)
         5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
         6 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
      >  7 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
           |                   ^
         8 |   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
         9 | });
        10 | 

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.645s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.
```

---

#### Too Long; Did not Read (TL;DR)

1. Do not add `jest` using `yarn add --dev jest` or `npm install --save-dev jest` if you use `create-react-app` command. `jest` is included in `node-modules` of the project if you use `create-react-app`.

From [official Jest documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html):

> **Setup with Create React App**
>
> If you are just getting started with React, we recommend using Create
>   React App. It is ready to use and ships with Jest! You don't need to
>   do any extra steps for setup, and can head straight to the next
>   section.

2. Do not change the test script in `package.json` file { [look at this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2564) }. Keep the default `"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",` in that.

Comment: this answer is very incomplete. Should add the relevant explanation to the answer instead of just redirecting to the issue.

Comment: @episodeyang, I am still looking to get a better answer. Can you lend a hand?

Comment: @arsho I believe you can fix it by uninstalling jest. I explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Just remove `jest` from your dev dependencies. To do so, run the following command:

```
npm remove --save-dev jest
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: But what happen if I am not using create react app?

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

to your package.json file, your package.json would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "jest-demo-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^22.0.4"
  },
   "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

for the people using create app and having this problem, there are two solutions.

1- update `test`command (or add new one) in *package.json* to `jest`  instead of `react-scripts test`, because `react-scripts test` will not allow jest options in *package.json* as  @Xinyang_Li stated in comments.

2-if you don't want to change test command in package.json, and use default create-react-app test; remove jest options from packge.json (if exists)

```
 "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

then **remove *node_modules*** and then run **npm install** to install them all again, and after that your tests should run normally.

Comment: this won't work if your project is bootstrapped using `create-react-app` unless you eject it.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have updated the answer, please take a look.

Comment: @XinyangLi thats true if you use default test command, but here we are using "jest" in test command and it works fine

Answer (score 4):

My issue solve with this:
.
If you have both react-scripts and jest in your package.json, delete jest from it.
Then delete package-lock.json, yarn.lock and node_modules.
Then run *npm install* (or *yarn* if you use it). ~Dan Abramov~
.
[issues #5119](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5119)
.

Answer (score 1):

You should downgrade installed `jest` to `v20.0.4`
`npm install -D jest@20.0.4`

Comment: This worked for me. is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Downgrading is not a proper solution.

Comment: So - do the magic by youself - it's incompatible with newer versions :D

Comment: This error can occur even on jest v20.0.4. While downgrading may solve for some people, it's at best a workaround.

Comment: @FDisk, please take a look at my updated answer and tell if it does the magic. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is an older issue but I was facing the same problem. We have `react-scripts` package and it uses Jest version `20.x.x` which has problems with `coverageTreshold`. I couldn't use newer `react-scripts` version and the only thing helped was to use yarn resolutions, read more here https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/.