# TypeError: environment.setup is not a function react test jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

i'm try simple unit test but getting error like my titte

> package.json

```
{
 "name": "react-unit-test",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "^15.6.2",
 "react-dom": "^15.6.2"
},
 "devDependencies": {
 "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
 "babel-jest": "^22.4.1",
 "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
 "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
 "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
 "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5",
 "jest": "^22.4.2",
 "jest-cli": "^22.4.2",
 "jest-enzyme": "^4.2.0",
 "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
 "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
},
 "scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "jest",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
 "jest": {
  "setupFiles": [
   "./test/setupJest.js"
  ]
 }
}
```

> .babelrc

```
{
 "presets": [
 "es2015",
 "react",
 "stage-2",
 "jest"
 ]
}
```

i using node version 8.0.0, some issue some case need downgrade on node v5.11.1. but it's not working

Comment: looks like this is a duplicate. Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48149004/typeerror-environment-setup-is-not-a-function-in-react-testing